Is $\space S^c\cup \{\vec{0}\}\space$ an accurate construction for the supplementary subspace of $S$?
Let $\space V\space$ be a vector space and $\space S\subseteq V\space$ a subspace. When considering the supplementary subspace i.e $\space W\space$ such that $\space V = S \oplus W$,  is  $\space W = \ S^c\cup \{\vec{0}\}$ ? I want a set construction for it besides just "considering it such that..." .
I am aware it is the orthogonal complement, but I am working without having introduced a metric so I cannot talk about orthogonality.
$S^c$ here denotes the set complement of $S$.

Did you try the simplest examples? Is $S^c\cup{0}$ a subspace? Perhaps you are not a native English speaker, but "the supplementary subspace" suggests that there is a uniquely determined supplementary subspace. There certainly is not. There are infinitely many possible choices, with a unique choice only if you indeed introduce an inner product on $V$. You're going to have to work with bases.

The orthogonal complement when $V$ is a Hilbert space (which is not always the case, as in your situation) is the closest you'll get to a "canonical" construction of a supplementary subspace, as there are always infinitely many supplementary subspaces, hence it doesn't always make sense to choose one of them as "the one". To see why it suffices to pick any nonzero vector $u$ in $W$, write $W$ as $W_0 \oplus \operatorname{span} u$ (note that $W_0$ is itself non-unique...), choose any $v \in (W_0 \oplus S)^c \cap (\operatorname{span} u)^c$ and see that $\tilde{W} := W_0 \oplus \operatorname{span} v$ is a new supplementary subspace to $S$ (can you check why?).
What you can do if you want a set construction is looking at the quotient $V/S$ of $V$ by $S$, as all supplementary subspaces of $S$ in $V$ are isomorphic to $V / S$ and $V/S$ has a "canonical" construction, however the trade-off of that point of view is that it is not a subspace of $V$ anymore but a set of equivalence classes of vectors of $V$.
Finally, the construction you proposed is never a subspace to begin with unless $S$ is already trivial:
Suppose $S$ is neither $V$ nor $\{0\}$. Suppose ad absurdam that $W := S^c \cup \{0\}$ is a subspace, and consider $u \in W$, $u \neq 0$. Take any $v \in S$, $v \neq 0$. Since $S$ is a subspace, $u + v$ cannot belong to $S$ as otherwise $(u + v) - v = u$ would belong to $S$, and $u + v$ cannot belong to $W$ because otherwise $(u + v) - u = v$ would belong to $W$ and hence $S^c$. Thus $u+v \notin S \cup W = V$, contradiction, and your $W$ cannot be a subspace if $S$ is neither $V$ nor $\{0\}$.

I'm struggling to see how there are infinitely many supplementary subspaces. The definition I'm using is the subspace satisfying: $S+W=V$ and $S\cap W = { \vec{0} }$. How is this not unique?

@RealityIsSenseless I already constructed infinitely many subspaces for any non-trivial $S$ in the first paragraph, but let's look at a simple example: consider $V = \mathbb{R}^2$, $S = \operatorname{span} (1,0)$ i.e. the $x$-axis. Then any line $L = \operatorname{span} (x_1, y_1)$ passing through the origin which isn't $S$ itself is a subspace of $V$ which is supplementary to $S$: indeed, to construct any vector $(x,y)$ as a linear combination $\alpha (x_1, y_1) + \beta (1, 0)$, you can and must take $\alpha$ such that $y = \alpha y_1$, and then $\beta$ can and must be $x - \alpha x_1$.

True. Thank you very much.
